# Advanced linq expression with multiple joins

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have the follwing EF Entities :

**Candidate**

1. User (User)
2. CandidateId (Guid)
3. CandidateNumber (Integer)

**User**

1. UserId (Guid)
2. UserName (Guid)
3. Roles (Set)
4. Candidates (Set)

**Role**

1. RoleId (Guid)
2. Rolename (String)
3. Users (Set)

As You see each Candidate has UserId - which is the foreign key of the creator of the specific candidate. What I need is to retrieve all Candidates that relevent to the creator and to the other users which in the same roles as the current user.

For example, I am the current user - which is FOO, and FOO is in role MY_ROLE. 
Also user BOO is in the same role MY_ROLE.
so I need the linq query (c#) which will retrieve all candidates
created by FOO and by BOO and filtered just by the current user which is FOO.

In TSQL - is actually very simple to do. But in LINQ...it's much more complicated to me.

Here is my sql:

```
SELECT Candidates.*
FROM UsersInRoles 
    INNER JOIN Users ON UsersInRoles.UserId = Users.UserId    
    INNER JOIN Candidates ON Users.UserId = Candidates.UserId 
    INNER JOIN Roles ON UsersInRoles.RoleId = Roles.RoleId 
    WHERE ( Roles.RoleId IN 
                  ( SELECT UsersInRoles.RoleId FROM UsersInRoles 
                     WHERE UsersInRoles.UserId = 'C6B9F0EF-7F23-4BB7-A7DB-DA614B389B13'
                   ) 
               )
```

Thank You.

Comment: Would be easier to answer if you post your SQL query first.

Comment: Here are my TSQL : SELECT        Candidates.*
FROM            UsersInRoles INNER JOIN
                         Users ON UsersInRoles.UserId = Users.UserId INNER JOIN
                         Candidates ON Users.UserId = Candidates.UserId INNER JOIN
                         Roles ON UsersInRoles.RoleId = Roles.RoleId
       WHERE ( Roles.RoleId IN ( SELECT UsersInRoles.RoleId FROM UsersInRoles WHERE UsersInRoles.UserId = 'C6B9F0EF-7F23-4BB7-A7DB-DA614B389B13' ) )

Answer (score 0):

To start i think you want something like this.

```
var userNames = new [] {"FOO", "BOO"};

var candidates = User.Where(p => userNames.Contains(p.UserName)).Select(p => p.Candidates);
```